# Does it make sense to use ANOVA with one-hot-encoded data?

Tags: anova, categorical-data, feature-selection, binary-data, categorical-encoding

I have a data set with different feature types (numerical and categorical). I applied one-hot-encoding to the categorical features and then used ANOVA to find most relevant features. 6 of 66 features in total produce a result that almost as good as when using all feature. These 6 contain 3 numeric and 3 (binary features - which are result of one-hot-encoding). The results are good and I showed which feature are most relevant but **the question is** whether it was okay to apply ANOVA to these binary features?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing specifically about one-hot encoding that makes ANOVA inappropriate.

Most software (certainly R and SAS) does some version of coding of categorical variables for you. With R and SAS (and maybe others) you can choose among various parameterizations for categorical variables (effect coding, dummy coding, Helmert contrasts etc.)

Comment: Since ANOVA asuumes that data is normally distributed it could be not appropriate because one hot encoded data may be not normally distributed?

Comment: @methus ANOVA does not assume that the data are normally distributed

Comment: Some assumptions I found: https://www.technologynetworks.com/informatics/articles/one-way-vs-two-way-anova-definition-differences-assumptions-and-hypotheses-306553 

What are the assumptions of a One-Way ANOVA?

1) Normality – That each sample is taken from a normally distributed population;

2) Sample independence – that each sample has been drawn independently of the other samples;

3) Variance Equality – That the variance of data in the different groups should be the same;

4) The dependent variable should be continuous

Comment: 1) How can I assume that the one-hot-encoded data (binary data) is taken from a normally distributed population? 2) Since one-hot-encoded data is binary, these type of data is also not continuous

Comment: Neither of those things is a problem for ANOVA.  ANOVA does NOT assume the data are normal and does NOT assume the independent variables are continuous.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but this confuses me a lot because I have read in many sources that ANOVA has all these assumptions about the data. I have looked at the implementation of anova (f_classif) and it says the following: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c4/sklearn/feature_selection/_univariate_selection.py#L64

Comment: The ANOVA test has important assumptions that must be satisfied in order
    for the associated p-value to be valid.
    1. The samples are independent
    2. Each sample is from a normally distributed population
    3. The population standard deviations of the groups are all equal. This
       property is known as homoscedasticity.
    If these assumptions are not true for a given set of data, it may still be
    possible to use the Kruskal-Wallis H-test (`scipy.stats.kruskal`_) although
    with some loss of power.

Comment: If all sources indicate these different assumptions about ANOVA, how can you be so sure that all these assumptions are wrong?

Comment: These assumptions are all different wordings of the same thing. The RESIDUALS have to be normal, which is the same as saying the conditional means have to be normal, which is the same as 2. in what you wrote.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Then there are two remaining problems: 1) How can I be sure that the residuals of the binary features are normal? 2) The variance of the binary variable is equal to $p_i(1-p_i)$ where $p_i$ is the probability of getting "value 1" in group $i$ (or, equivalently, the mean outcome for
group $i$). Therefore groups with different means have different variances, violating the equal variance assumption. (Source: [link](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~hseltman/309/Book/chapter16.pdf))

Comment: 3) is the choice of the $\chi^2$ test perhaps more reasonable than ANOVA in this case? and 4) when using ANOVA is okay: is it okay to compare the p-values of different types of features (numerical binary) and perform the feature selection based on these p-values?

Comment: I did not know about effect coding, Helmert contrasts ... Where can I read about alternative encodings of categorical variables (besides onehot)?